# Django: ImportError: No module named pocdebug_toolbar

Tags: python, django, django-debug-toolbar

I'm getting this error when starting Django from uWSGI and can't figure out what's wrong:

```
...
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 160, in _fetch
    app = import_module(appname)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named pocdebug_toolbar
```

Python 2.7.3; Django==1.4.3; Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS

```
Here is the full traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 241, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in get_response
    response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 221, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 66, in technical_500_response
    html = reporter.get_traceback_html()  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 287, in get_traceback_html
    return t.render(c)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 140, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 134, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 823, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 74, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 84, in render
    output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 599, in resolve
    new_obj = func(obj, *arg_vals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/defaultfilters.py", line 718, in date
    return format(value, arg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/dateformat.py", line 310, in format
    return df.format(format_string)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/dateformat.py", line 33, in format
    pieces.append(force_unicode(getattr(self, piece)()))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/dateformat.py", line 214, in r
    return self.format('D, j M Y H:i:s O')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/dateformat.py", line 33, in format
    pieces.append(force_unicode(getattr(self, piece)()))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/encoding.py", line 71, in force_unicode
    s = unicode(s)  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 121, in __unicode_cast
    return func(*self.__args, **self.__kw)  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 86, in ugettext
    return _trans.ugettext(message)  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 278, in ugettext
    return do_translate(message, 'ugettext')  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 268, in do_translate
    _default = translation(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 183, in translation
    default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 160, in _fetch
    app = import_module(appname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named pocdebug_toolbar
```

Comment: This is a pretty impossible question to answer as you've framed it. We have no idea what packages you have installed on your system, what your path is, how you installed the packages you're using...  We just can't help you much if this is all you say.  Also, I think there's another stack exchange site that is better suited to this kind of question (http://stackexchange.com/sites), maybe Ask Ubuntu, Server Fault, or Superuser.

Comment: What does your `INSTALLED_APPS` contain?  Seems like you have `pocdebug_toolbar` listed instead of `debug_toolbar`.

Comment: You nailed it -- thanks @Austin_Phillips!  I forgot a comma between my two apps in the INSTALLED_APPS tuple, so the strings got concatenated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.  I forgot a comma between my apps in the `settings.py` `INSTALLED_APPS` tuple, so it was concatenating the two strings 'poc' and 'debug_toolbar' into 'pocdebug_toolbar'.

> ```
> INSTALLED_APPS = (
>    ...
>    'poc'  # <== missing comma here
>    'debug_toolbar'
>    )
> ```